# How to Download Audio from URL using android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-download-manager

I'm new to android and for trainning i want to create an app that downloads audio from existing api.

i'm getting the link to downloading the file from the api, but i can't get it download properly

i've tried with download manager, in which, didn't even download it although it said it did.

here's the main code:

```
public void Download(String link)
{
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)m_context.getSystemService(m_context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
       Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(link);
       DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

       //Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
       request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
       //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
       request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
       //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
       request.setTitle("Downloading " + m_name);
       //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
       request.setDescription("Downloader");
       //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
       request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(m_context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, m_name +".mp3");

       //Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
       downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

m_context is MainActivity
link is url that contains the file for downloading.
I'm using broadcast receiver to see if the download completed, and it did so i try to open it but nothing happens.

I've also tried to download it without the DownloadManager, even though it downloaded it, the size is very very small (1-15 kb) but sometimes(not most of the time maybe 5%) it gives me the complete audio(according to size and time)
here's the code:

```
public void Download(final String link)
{
    try {
        Thread t= new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                int count;

                 try {

                        URL url = new URL(link);
                        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();                  
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                        conexion.connect();
                        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                        // downlod the file                         
                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());                          

                        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                        if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/Music",m_name+".mp3");
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                        long total = 0;

                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;                                                         
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        downloadSuccess = false;
                 e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        };
        t.start();  
        t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            downloadSuccess = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

you will see thread.sleep, i've assumed that the response needs a little time to process but even a minute didn't finish.

Any guidance will be appreciated
Thank you

**UPDATE:**
There's something called GZIPInputStream  that the encoding of the files that failed download correctly are in gzip 
peace of code:

```
 if ("gzip".equals(httpConn.getContentEncoding())) {
                            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream())));                               
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String read;
                            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null){
                                sb.append(read);
                            }                               
                        }
```

it's still not helping me to download in the correct way but i think it's the right path, and again any help will be great. thank you